# Creating dynamic form by multidimensional array

Tags: php, symfony

I have multidimensional array (settings system) with string values. I need to create able to  changing this array by admin. I think, it will be form. So, how I can create dynamic form by input array in symfony2? Is exist true solution for resolve that?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a dynamic form with use Form Listeners.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html